How Can I connect my computer terminal to ESP32 via Bluetooth?
I am working on a bluetooth project and couldn't find any info about connecting my terminal to esp32 only using bluetooth. I am using PlatformIO extension for VS Code. Either I cannot find the correct COM to connect or there should be another wa to do this I am guessing.
//This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)
//By Evandro Copercini - 2018
//
//This example creates a bridge between Serial and Classical Bluetooth (SPP)
//and also demonstrate that SerialBT have the same functionalities of a normal Serial

#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32_HAND"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}


Which ESP32 device exactly are you using? Serial-over-bluetooth only works with classical Bluetooth, not Bluetooth Low Energy. Many newer members of the ESP32 family only support BLE, not classic BT, e.g. ESP32-S3, ESP32-C3 etc.

NodeMCU version

NodeMCU boards use different versions of the ESP32 family.
